# Substitute string on condition

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a hash:

```
%hash = ("dog1" => "1", 
         "dog2" => "2",
         "dog3" => "3");
```

and a string:

```
$string = "dog1 dog2 dog3";
```

I need to replace all "dog" in the `$string` with `cat` if the value of the dog in the hash is odd. So in the end I want my string to be:

```
"cat1 dog2 cat3"
```

How can I do it with a regex? I can easily change all dogs into cats:

```
$string =~ s/dog/cat/g;
```

but that's not I want. Is there a way I can substitute with regex conditionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/e` modifier. From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators): *`/e` will cause the replacement portion to be treated as a full-fledged Perl expression and evaluated right then and there*. For example:

```
$string=~s/(dog(\d+))/$hash{$1}%2==0?$1:"cat$2"/eg;
print $string; #prints cat1 dog2 cat3
```